# Are arbitrary iOS deployment targets allowed?

Tags: ios, xcode, deployment, xcode5, settings

If, for instance, I have an iOS application that needs fixes that were introduced in iOS 7.0.3, am I allowed to set the deployment target to 7.0.3 and submit it to the app store?

I can’t find any definitive documentation on it and Xcode doesn’t seem to complain when I set it, build or archive, but nobody I know has done this or knows whether or not it’s allowed.

*NOTE: I know Xcode only shows minor versions in the drop down menu, but you can fill in arbitrary versions in the textfield.*

Specifically I’m looking for:

- Apple documentation that states it is or isn’t allowed to target patch versions.
- Personal experience with (recently) submitting an app that targets a patch version.
- *If* targeting patch versions is allowed, in my specific example where I set the deployment target to 7.0.3 am I correct in understand that I should set the base SDK to 7.0.0?

Comment: Can you add some conditional code for iOS < 7.0.3 and use a workaround there instead?

Comment: Yeah indeed, but this was meant as an arbitrary hypothetical situation, so I’m not looking for workarounds in this case, but for answers to the exact question instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set minor revision number (what you call patch).

When you fill the textbox, [according to this documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Configuring/configuring.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000163i-CH1-SW1), it sets the variable `MinimumOSVersion`.

> When you build your application, your deployment target is reflected in the MinimumOSVersion entry in the application’s Info.plist file. For iOS apps, the MinimumOSVersion entry is used by the App Store to indicate the iOS release requirement.

So if you go [to the documentation of this variable](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html), you find out that :

> MinimumOSVersion (String - iOS). When you build an iOS app, Xcode uses the iOS Deployment Target setting of the project to set the value for the MinimumOSVersion key. Do not specify this key yourself in the Info.plist file; it is a system-written key. When you publish your app to the App Store, the store indicates the iOS releases on which your app can run based on this key. **It is equivalent to the LSMinimumSystemVersion key in OS X**.

and

> MinimumOSVersion
>   “Minimum system version”
>   Do not use. Use “LSMinimumSystemVersion” instead.

(I suppose XCode fill it for you and precise that you target iOS.)

And then, if you continues to follow the documentation, you arrive [to the reference of `LSMinimumSystemVersion`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-113253), which is precise :

> LSMinimumSystemVersion (String - OS X) indicates the minimum version of OS X required for this app to run. **This string must be of the form n.n.n** where n is a number. The first number is the major version number of the system. The second and **third numbers are minor revision numbers**. For example, to support OS X v10.4 and later, you would set the value of this key to “10.4.0”.

So you can specify a minor revision number and according to the documentation `the MinimumOSVersion entry is used by the App Store to indicate the iOS release requirement.` it should work.

And for your third question, there isn't 7.0.3 iOS SDK, so you should use the 7.0 SDK or 7.1 SDK (when available). [Since 1st February, you can't use prior version of the SDK.](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=12172013a)

But to answer your question (I think), you can use SDK higher and equal to your target iOS version. So if you target 6.1, you can use 7.0 SDK. And you can use 7.0SDK if you target 7.0.3 (since it is, in the end 7.0.x so equal).

I don't have personal experience, but I'm pretty sure Apple respects what is say in reference and documentation :)

Comment: Thanks, that looks like the right docs that I was missing indeed. We’re going to try a release, I will update after we’ve done that.

Comment: It wasn't easy to find it I admit ;)